# Live Streaming Protocol Backend

Tags: laravel, streaming, live, backend, rtsp

I am currently working on live streaming music project. My first focus is web-based application. Front-end was not a problem for me, but backend I am still doing some researches about web-based live streaming. Since Laravel has the greatest community in the planet,I am used Laravel as my backend from now. Anyone has experienced on live streaming programming, Real Time Streaming Protocol (RTSP)? Looking for professional advice and suggestions/recommendations.

Comment: how do you capture the incoming audio-video data like in H223, H245 protoco?

Comment: When you say "frontend wasn't a problem", what kind of frontend? Do you target only mobile apps? Desktop browser? Mobile browser? The reason I ask is that understanding client requirements helps to select the backend.